# Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1 << audio stream

Tags: ffmpeg

Cutting clips with -ss -to issue!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8tbC.png)

I get following error,

Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1 << audio stream!

2 frames left in the queue on closing..

### Conversion failed!

How to solve this issue?

-ss and -to is after the input file!

-c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686244/ffmpeg-too-many-packets-buffered-for-output-stream-01

Comment: Found the solution! Just add, -i file.mp4 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999

Comment: You can answer your own question.